# What is the difference in meaning between "Are you for real" and "Are you of real"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between "Are you for real" and "Are you of real" ?

By the way, Is the "preposition + adjective (for real)" structure grammatically possible?

Does "Are you for real" mean "Are you agree that it is real"?
Does "for real" mean "agree that it is real"?

Comment: Extra info https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170941/saying-something-is-for-real-vs-just-saying-something-is-real

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Are you of real** is not idiomatic. **Are you for real** is a slang idiom that violates the general rule that the object of a preposition must be a noun or pronoun.

The idiom means, depending on context, **did you really say that** or **did you really mean that** or **did you really do that.** It is an expression of mild shock or disbelief.

Answer (score 2):

- Are you for real? is from the idiom **to be for real**, a colloquial AmE expression that means: Is what you are saying or doing really true?

In this case, as an idiom, one just uses it. The grammar is overridden by usage. This is true in many idiomatic expressions.

to be of real is not an idiomatic expression and also would not be used.